# About PHP array with string

Tags: php

I am testing following PHP code. I want to change a series of string with html into array from a xml. 
I can get this array:

```
Array 
( 
     [0] => Yellow Fire Danger Warning 
     [1] => ( 11:40 HKT - 28.01.2020 ) 
     [2] => Cold Weather Warning 
     [3] => ( 16:20 HKT - 26.01.2020 ) 
     [4] =>
)
```

I want to detect some specific keywords (elements) in the array. I try to use for loop and if case to do it. However, the if case , it seems that it cannot compare the string.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://rss.weather.gov.hk/rss/WeatherWarningSummary.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$x=$xml->channel[0]->item[0]->description . "<br>";

print_r(explode("<br/>",$x));

$arr=explode("<br/>",$x);

$arrLength=count($arr);

for ($i=0; $i<=$arrLength; $i++)
{
if ($arr[$i]=="Cold Weather Warning")
{
    echo "<img src='https://www.hko.gov.hk/tc/wxinfo/dailywx/images/cold.gif'>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the fetched string value in the `if statement`:

```
if (trim($arr[$i]) === "Cold Weather Warning")
{
    echo "<img src='https://www.hko.gov.hk/tc/wxinfo/dailywx/images/cold.gif'>";
}
```